# Finding $f^{(m)}(i)$ where $f(z) = (1 + (z - i)^2)^{-1}$ without differentiating.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

I have a question and I'm not to sure how to approach it, so any kind of help will be awesome. I was given this question in the practice final, however there are no solutions/hints to this question, and on top I haven't done questions like this on assignments. Also I'm new to this material so please do bear with my silly questions regarding this topic.

> [image]

Thank you everyone for all your help.

Comment: When $|z - i| < 1$ this function can be validly written as a Taylor series (even with complex values).

Comment: "how do i show that m = 2n is even and m = 2n+1 is odd?" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Taylor series, the function is:

$$
f(z) = \sum_0^\infty \frac{f^m(i)}{m!}(z - i)^m = \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n(z - i)^{2n}
$$

So when $m = 2n$, then

$$
(-1)^n = \frac{f^m(i)}{m!} \rightarrow f^m(i) = (-1)^n m!
$$

But recall, this is when $m = 2n$ so we have $f^m(i) = (-1)^n(2n)!$, and when $m = 2n + 1$ there *is* no coefficient (because from the original Taylor expansion we *only* have $(z - i)^{2n}$--no odd values).

Comment: This is very well explained. Thank you clearing all my questions.

Answer (score 3):

The theme here is that the $m$th coefficient of the power series expansion is given by the $m$th derivative (times some factorials). This question hinges on the fact that this is a geometric  series, and so we can just write down the expansion.

More explicitly, recall that
$$ \frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$$
So we have that
$$ \frac{1}{1 + (z - i)^2} = 1 - (z-i)^2 + (z-i)^4 + \dots$$
This is a power series centered at $i$. We also know that the $m$th coefficient should be
$$ \frac{f^m(i)}{m!}.$$
Comparing gives your answer.

Comment: Thank you, for all your input.

Comment: @mixedmath: This seems the clearer answer (+1)